# Can you map a set of characters to a set of integers?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

So if I had a set $A$ containing $\{a,b,c,d\}$, would I be able to map that to a set of integers? Could I call that an injective map and how would I give an example of that relation?

Edit: I understand that an injective map is a 1 to 1 mapping from the domain and range, so that every element in the range only has 1 element from the domain.

Thanks very much for help, I think I'm understanding it now. Apologies for the poorly worded question, I aim to improve this.

Comment: Please edit you post to include the definition of an injective function that you've learned, and add your thoughts on what such an injective map might look like, in terms of the example you posted.  We can certainly then clarify, or confirm, or elaborate.

Comment: $$\{(a,34), (b,11), (c, -1), (d, 2^{44939})\}$$

Comment: Thanks very much for the edit advice!

Answer (score 1):

You always can map a finite set to the integers, and you can choose any map (since you have infinite possibilities).

For example consider $A$ be any finite set with $n$ elements, then you can write $A=\lbrace a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n \rbrace$ and map to $\mathbb{Z}$ by the identity map as $f:A\to \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and $f(a_i)=i$. Where $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ denote the set of positive integers.

Notice that $f$ is an injective map as well.

As I tell you this trivial map is not the unique form of map a finite set, for example we can choose $f(a_{i})=2i$ or $f(a_i)=3i$ and you can always use infinitely many's $f$.

Comment: This might be a correct answer. There is really no way to tell since the question is not well formulated. I'm glad you want to help by answering, but sometimes the best strategy is to ask the OP to clarify before jumping in. They might learn more that way.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I appreciate a lot your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can map any finite (or even a countably infinite) set of characters to a set of integers.  In fact, in software development, there's a standard for doing so called [Unicode](https://home.unicode.org/), which attempts to map every character used in every language in the world to an integer “code point”.  The letters `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are mapped to the numbers 97, 98, 99, and 100, respectively.